# How to Express Volkenborn Integral with Representative of $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I'm reading through a part of W. H. Schikof's Ultrametric Calculus and on page 170 and a specific case of an identity presented there is,

$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}_p} f(x) dx = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{n=0}^{p-1} \int_{\mathbb{Z}_p} f(n+px) dx$$

To me this seems intuitive, since this would run over all of the representatives of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, each from $(0+p \mathbb{Z}_p) \cup (1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)\cup (2+p \mathbb{Z}_p)\cup \cdots \cup (p-1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)$, so to give an explicit example of two calculations that I believe should give the same result,

This gives the correct result
$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} f(x)dx = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=0}^4 \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} f(n+5x) dx$$

This gives the incorrect result
$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} f(x)dx = \frac{1}{5} \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} f(0+5x) dx + \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=1}^4 \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} f(i^n+5x) dx$$

Despite it being that 0, 1, i, -1, and -i are all representatives corresponding to some $n+p \mathbb{Z}_p$. So what is my misconception here and/or how do I amend this in the spirit of my reasoning if possible?

EDIT:

To try to clear up my working of a specific case, let's pick the simple f(x)=x. It is already known that $$\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx = \frac{-1}{2}$$. I'll go ahead and expand the integral in the way I described,

$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{5} \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} (0+5x) dx + \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=1}^4 \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} (i^n+5x) dx$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx + \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=1}^4 \left(i^n\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5}  dx+5\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x  dx\right)$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx + \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=1}^4 i^n \left(\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5}  dx\right)+ \sum_{n=1}^4 \left(\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x  dx\right)$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx + 0\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5}dx+ 4\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x  dx$$
$$= 5\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x  dx $$

In other words, I've just shown that,

$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx = 5\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx$$
implying that,
$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} x dx = 0$$
Which contradicts with it being equal to -1/2. I'm looking very closely at each of my steps but I can't find anything objectionable.

Comment: Why is the second evaluation incorrect?

Comment: In your last integral, you mean $i^j$ instead of $i^n$, right? (And I assume "$i$" is a primitive fourth root of unity -- I admit I don't like this mix of complex and $p$-adic notation, would rather call it $\xi_4$ or $\zeta_4$.)

Comment: I worked out several calculations by hand, for instance, if we look at f(x)=x then I have that the part with powers of i cancels itself out leaving effectively a multiple of the original integral, $\int x dx = \frac{1}{5} \int 5x dx + \frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^4 \int (i^n+5x) dx = \int x dx + \frac{1}{5}\int \left( \sum_{n=1}^4 i^n \right) dx +  4\int x dx = 5 \int x dx$ Which is clearly not the case since it would mean the integral is 0. Hopefully that's readable cramming all this into the box, and your assumptions are correct @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: I think I see my mistake in plain sight, I've blindly assumed linearity, $\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5} (a+x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{Z}_5}a dx +\int_{\mathbb{Z}_5}x dx $

Comment: Well on second thought, I don't see why that would be an issue. I've tried to work out this example in my comment more explicitly by editing my post to try to expose what is the problem but I've scrutinized each step and missed it. Maybe I'll sleep on it, and realize the misstep. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm. I don't have Schikhof's book ready; could you expand a bit on the identity he gives and the context there? My next guess would be that either $f$ has to be locally constant, or one has to restrict the domain of integration on the right side.

Comment: @StevenGrigsby: Can you? (see last comment)

Comment: I'm kind of in a catch 22, I think if I could give you the context I wouldn't need to ask in the first place. It's just too deeply buried in the book I think for me to unravel it. I'm taking a break from this kind of p-adic integral which I thought was the Haar measure p-adic integral I had been really interested in for zeta functions of groups previously; but really this is a different, but similar, kind of p-adic integral. I'll probably try to answer this question myself in the future, but I am just learning about p-adics as a hobby. I appreciate the help though.